# Using one string twice in list of Python

Tags: python

I am trying to use two string inside the following list and want to use one string two times. I mean I do not want to write one word twice inside my list or tuple.

My output is -

Hi, Maggie. Maggie I will go to market to buy pencil and book.

Hi, Lulu. Lulu I will go to market to buy pencil and book.

But my error is : tuple index out of range
Is it possible to write maggie / lulu one time inside my tuple and use it in two places?

My code is:

```
first_tuple = ("magi","book","pencil")
second_tuple = ("lulu","copy","eraser")

together = (first_tuple, second_tuple)
New_List = list(together)


for i in range (len(New_List)):
    print ("Hi, {}. {} I will go to market to buy {} and {} .".format(*New_List[i]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
print ("Hi, {0}. {0} I will go to market to buy {1} and {2} .".format(*New_List[i]))
```

The numbers in braces are an index into the list of format parameters. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) for details.

Comment: If I want to use: %s like:                 print ("Hi, %s[0]. %s[0] I will go to market to buy %s[1] and %s[2] ." %(New_List[i]))           --my code is not working. What can I do solve this?

Comment: @hapy Repeating the same item twice and using index numbers is not possible with the old, printf-based `%`-formatting language.